# Failed to render and update auto layout in storyboard. Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, material-components

I'm using Xcode 9.4 and MaterialComponents. Project builds and runs normally, but storyboard throws following error:

```
Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): dlopen(MaterialComponents.framework, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/MDFInternationalization.framework/MDFInternationalization
  Referenced from: MaterialComponents.framework
  Reason: image not found
```

It happens when I add any element from MaterialComponents to storyboard it stops displaying anything in designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is the problem with Cocoapod version 1.5.0
If you are using this you will get this error.

To remove your current version you could just run:

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

you can install a specific version of cocoa pods via the following command:

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0